# Monitoring API Response from angular

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to monitor an api response to know if the user is currently logged in or not. To do so, I'm sending a get request to /api/status along with the http-only cookie. the endpoint should respond with my userid if I am currently logged in. If am logged in, angular should not show the login/register links.
My code is as follows:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  authService = inject(AuthService)

  isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);

  authenticationStatus!: Observable<HttpResponse<object>>;

  constructor() {
    this.authenticationStatus = this.authService.authStatus()

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authenticationStatus.subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        if (res.body) {
          const userId = res.body.message;
          console.log("User ID: ", userId);
          this.isLoggedIn$.next(true)
          console.log(this.isLoggedIn$.value);
        } else this.isLoggedIn$.next(false)
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err)
        this.isLoggedIn$.next(false)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

authStatus() : Observable<HttpResponse>{
return this.http.get(`${apiUrls.authServiceApi}/status`,
{ observe: 'response', withCredentials: true });
}

then in the template, I use:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoggedIn$.value">
      <span
        [routerLink]="['/login']"
        routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
        class="text-xl cursor-pointer text-gray-200 font-bold m-3 hover:underline hover:text-indigo-200"
        >Login</span
      >
      <span
        [routerLink]="['/register']"
        routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
        class="text-xl cursor-pointer text-gray-200 font-bold m-3 hover:underline hover:text-indigo-200"
        >Register</span
      >
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that the login/register links don't disappear after logging in till I refresh the page. Any ideas?

I'm expecting the isLoggedIn variable to be updated.

Comment: as mentionned above you should use the async pipe also are you using onPush stategy somewhere in the parent component?

Comment: I have async pipe. It's not helping. I don't have onPush anywhere.

Comment: I suspect the error never gets called

Answer (score 0):

You have `isLoggedIn$.value` in your template. I suspect .value on your observable. I dont think it returns the last emitted value.

You can use async pipe to subscribe to an observable.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoggedIn$ | async">
```

Comment: hi. that didn't work. maybe because the value is already initialized to false? How do I monitor changes?

Comment: What happening when you use log in your res.body block ?

Answer (score 0):

The asObservable() method of BehaviorSubject is used to convert it into an observable, allowing only observation and prohibiting direct calls to next(), error(), or complete() methods. This is useful when you want to expose only the observable part of the BehaviorSubject to consumers, preventing them from modifying its state directly.

```
 private isLoggedInSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean|null>(null);
 //Creates a new Observable with this Subject as the source
 isLoggedIn$ = isLoggedInSource.asObservable();
 this.isLoggedInSource.next(true);
 <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoggedIn$ | async">
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  authService = inject(AuthService)

  isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('IS INIT');
    this.authService.authStatus().pipe(
      tap( console.log ),
      tap( res => {
          this.isLoggedIn$.next(!!res?.body)
      } )
    ).subscribe(
      () => {},
      ( err ) => {
        console.log( err );
        this.isLoggedIn$.next( false );
      }
    )
  }
}
```

and in the html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn$ | async)">
```

this is more or less the same but can you give what's you result in the console?

Comment: it says what?looks like you method from your service not getting triggered

Comment: sorry, I had an issue with stackoverflow. upon logging, the console shows nothing. then after refreshing, it logs the http response.

Comment: @ht990332 can you show the code of `authStatus()`

Comment: authStatus(): Observable<HttpResponse<object>> {
    return this.http.get(`${apiUrls.authServiceApi}/status`,
      { observe: 'response', withCredentials: true });
  }

Comment: How do you load your component? is it loaded before ?

Comment: I've changed my code do you see the `IS INIT`when loading the component?

Comment: I've changed my code again try the subscribe method with this syntax

Comment: the header is loaded within the main app.component template: <app-header/>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer/>

Comment: /home, /login, /register, etc... are routes: export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login', loadComponent: () => import('./pages/login/login.component')
    },
  ....

Comment: I do not see `IS INIT` till first refresh

Comment: @ht990332 your problem come from here and not the http get, your component should be loaded somewhere into your stack of console log.Please look if you see it somewhere in your previous console log.NgOnInit not triggering when loading the component is really a strange behavior and if it persist you make an isuue in the angular repo

Comment: It's triggered but not early enough?

Comment: you told me it was triggered only on refresh.When not refreshed do you see it initialising in the console log history.If yes it should be earlier than when you see your component loading

Comment: no. I don't see anything in console before the refresh. maybe a synchronization issue?

Comment: please open an issue on angular's github

Comment: done. if you're curious, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54686

Comment: if you post a stackblitz please let me know and add it to your question.Best

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, there was a hint that I can resubscribing again and thus resetting the value of isLoggedin